# How to make a double line border UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, border

I'd like my buttons to have a double line border, like in the image.

Is there a way of doing it programatically?

[image: Edit button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative would be to create a stretchable image using the UIImage method resizableImageWithCapInsets.

What you do is to create an image that has the inside collapsed down to it's smallest possible size (1 pixel in this example) and then specify the sizes of the edges. When you create a UIImage that way it expands the middle to any desired size. This would give you your double border. You'd then install one of these stretchable images as the background image of your button set to resize in both dimensions.

EDIT: Remember to create your image a 3x size, then scale it down to 2x and 1x size, so it looks sharp on all the different devices. (We still have to support the iPad 2, which is non-retina. If you're iPhone only you can skip the 1x and just save @2x and @3x resolutions.)

Comment: Thanks, that will make it super easy to do.

Comment: @coopersita, Up-votes gratefully accepted if you think the answer is a good one. :)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is probably to add the button as a subview of another view, slightly inset, and then set a border on the view and the buttons layer.

Alternatively set a background image on the button (which could be generated in code by rendering a bezier path to an image).

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UIButton and override drawRect:

Here you can draw your border as you please using [CGContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405725/using-cgcontext-to-draw-line)

Hope this helps!